# How to make a recursive function that seaches files that contain a given word Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to make a function with Python 3 that gets a directory name and a string, and find all txt files that contain a given string. The result should be returned inside a list.

this is the code I wrote.

```
def searchDir(directory, s):
    """
    Recursively searches 'directory' for .txt files
    that contain string s.
    """
    filelist = []
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    for file in files:
        fullname = directory + '/' + file
        try:
            if os.path.isdir(fullname):
                searchDir(fullname)
            else:
                if fullname[-4:] == '.txt':
                    f = open(fullname, 'r')
                    for lines in f:
                        if s in lines:
                            filelist.append(fullname)
                            break
        except OSError:
            pass
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.walk()`:

```
import os

def wordsearch(directory, string):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            with open(path, "r") as f:
                if string in f.read():
                    result.append(path)
    return result
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use it

Comment: Thanks for the answer I finished it by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pathlib
sorted(pathlib.Path('.').glob('**/*'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I finished it by myself :)